# Start execution of existing SageMaker pipeline using Python SDK

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-sagemaker

[SageMaker documentatin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/run-pipeline.html#run-pipeline-prereq) explains how to run a pipeline, but it assumes I have just [defined it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/define-pipeline.html) and I have the object `pipeline` available.

How can I run an **existing** pipeline with [Python SDK](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html)?

I know how to read a pipeline with AWS CLI (i.e. `aws sagemaker describe-pipeline --pipeline-name foo`). Can the same be done with Python code? Then I would have `pipeline` object ready to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the Pipeline has been created, you can use the Python Boto3 SDK to make the [`StartPipelineExecution`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.start_pipeline_execution) API call.

```
response = client.start_pipeline_execution(
    PipelineName='string',
    PipelineExecutionDisplayName='string',
    PipelineParameters=[
        {
            'Name': 'string',
            'Value': 'string'
        },
    ],
    PipelineExecutionDescription='string',
    ClientRequestToken='string',
    ParallelismConfiguration={
        'MaxParallelExecutionSteps': 123
    }
)
```

If you prefer AWS CLI, the most basic call is:

```
aws sagemaker start-pipeline-execution --pipeline-name <name-of-the-pipeline>
```